# Fix cursor position

Tags: vim

In sublime there is this feature that when you type

```
function foo () {|
```

and then hit enter your cursor is in this position

```
function foo () {
    |
}
```

I am using vim-surround for brackets completion, but it is very annoying to navigate the cursor from this position after hitting enter

```
function foo () {
|}
```

Comment: not eligant but `ino {<CR> {<CR>}<ESC>O` in vimrc should do the trick

Comment: The `vim-surround` plugin doesn't deal with automatically inserting brackets nor with indentation manipulation. It's only used to add, change, remove surrounding characters. I would suggest disabling that plugin and seeing if it changes the behaviour you are seeing; If not, you should investigate the other plugins you are using.

Comment: The vim settings that deal with indentation are `autoindent and smartindent`. Perhaps the functionality you are seeing is related to these settings along with the filetype settings (different languages require different indentation rules)

Comment: I use the following mapping for quick creation of function: `nnoremap fun afunction() {<cr>}<Esc>ko`